# Does Intuit uk provide read only access to bank accounts like the american version

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, yodlee

Has anyone worked with Intuit UK before. I am trying to work out if they provide the same level of access to banking accounts in the UK as they do in the US. 
I have not read anything saying they do but I may be wrong.

If they don't is there any system for UK banks similar to intuit or yodlee?

Answer (score 1):

Yodlee do support user's permission based aggregation and provide read only access of banking accounts in UK.
If you want to contact Yodlee , use this [contact form](http://solutions.yodlee.com/YIDeveloperPortalContactUsLeadInquiryForm.html)